# control camera sensitivity

Tags: camera

What am looking for is the ability to control, i.e, to increase or decrease the speed at which I can rotate, pan and zoom when looking through the camera.

This can be either with the commands or with the api. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Rotating the camera:***

- press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate at normal speed
- press <kbd>R</kbd> and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to decrease the rotation speed
- press <kbd>R</kbd> and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to rotate by 5 increments
- press <kbd>R</kbd> and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to rotate by 1 increment

[image]

***Panning and zooming the camera:***

Enter the camera ***Fly Mode*** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and press:

- <kbd>E</kbd>/<kbd>Q</kbd> to pan up/down
- <kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> to pan left/right
- <kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd> to zoom in/out
- hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd> while panning or zooming to increase/decrease the camera speed (or do it using the <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>)

[image]

These are the most common *fly mode* shortcuts. For more options take a look at the bottom strip after entering the *fly mode*.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate the images and gifs. But, wondering there is a way I can control the sensitivity while I freely do the regular viewport navigations in the camera with out pressing bizzare shortcuts. To give more context I am looking for something similar to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhIr3.png. You find this in user preferences > input > ndof devices( 3D mouse ). Am i making sense ?

Comment: @sreenivas - get used to using Ctrl/Alt/Shift, they are common keys used during viewport navigation as well as property adjustment, they work similarly as you are dragging a value as well. For a 3d mouse, the sensitivity setting is comparable to the system mouse speed setting, which will have the same effect with the mouse sensitivity inside blender.

Comment: > `For a 3d mouse, the sensitivity setting is comparable to the system mouse speed setting, which will have the same effect with the mouse sensitivity inside blender.` I don't think changing the NDOF device sensitity is effecting the regular mouse sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Press 0 and set the camera.

In the outliner click the camera

In the camera tab

[image]

Click and drag mouse on focal length to zoom in and out

Click and drag mouse on Below shift x to pan right and left and shift y to pan up and down

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate your comment. But, I am looking for something in the similar lines @paul explained in the answer. Ability to control the sensitivity of the regular camera rotation, pan and zoom.